# How is the interface `en8` created on macOS?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, network-interface, macos

It looks like some of these `enX` interfaces are in fact virtual interfaces created for virtual machines on macOS "native" Hypervisor framework. Yet, I can't find documentation actually proving it nor code examples on how to create a virtual interface too.

This command prints the hardware interfaces on your machine:

```
$ networksetup -listallhardwareports
```

There is no `en8` interface listed as a HW port on my machine. Now, if I start a new VM (e.g., Hyperkit instance with Minikube), when I run `ifconfig` then `en8` will appear and will be bridged with `bridge100`.

If I want to create/destroy and/or manage these virtual interfaces, what are the currently available tools on macOS?